# Android application and an HTTP server on ubuntu

Tags: php, android, http, ubuntu

my problem is this: for a personal project, I have to connect to an Android application and an HTTP server on ubuntu (it must then send information to a robot control board).
But at the level of communication with the server in both directions, I really do not see how to do it, I'm not even on a http server is the best solution ... My searches have been failed ...
What are the tools that would allow me to send information to the server (which is on my computer), treat it and that he refers to my application?

Thank you!

Excuse my poor english :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with HTTP, but if you want real-time bi-directional communication and the phone is going to be on the same network as the server (no firewall issues) it might be simpler to use sockets directly.  A lot depends on how the server is talking to the robot; if the server already has a web interface, you of course want your Android client to right to that.  Look for the [HttpClient  class](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

Comment: thanks you for you answers. I want to be able to use my application anywhere so i will not use socket. And i don't want my server has an interface, i just want it is a brigde between my application and my computer ...